# icons for open door lock (and lock again), unlock and keep unlocked and lock and keep locked

Tags: icons

I am developing a smart home app. For the lock, there are three commands

1. Lock
2. Unlock it for 5 secs and Lock again
3. Unlock and keep it locked.

For these, I have to select icons. Can someone suggest me the icons for Keep Unlocked?

Comment: I assume number 3 is supposed to be "unlock and keep it unlocked?"

Comment: Hi dmSherazi, there are similar questions like yours at [graphicdesign stackexchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) like [those](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=icon+suggestion), you should try there.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation would be (assuming my though on 3 is correct):

[image: Lock icons]

Comment: I like your approach. Consider using green for “locked” (since the safest state is locked) and red for “unlocked” (the unsafe state). For the state “unlock 5 seconds”, consider using the same red icon for unlock and overlaying the text “5s”. A blue color might not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Stackexchange isn't supposed to be used for suggestions for a particular use, but more for patterns that can be used in many apps/sites. So I'll give a pretty generic answer.

You can combine icons like hieroglyphs to combine their meaning.

The ubiquitous power icon is made of a 1 and a 0. Shortcuts in windows explorer are a duplicate of the target icon combined with an arrow. Music players use circular arrows for repeat, and add a badge with the number 1 on it for repeat once.

So if you're using timed functions, you can look at combining a clock symbol with the original symbol. Of course a clock leaves some ambiguity because it could be a times operation or a scheduled one. But if your app only uses one of those time-relations, you should be fine.